# Google Play Console - Internal Testing - Where Are the ANRs?

Tags: google-play-console, google-play-internal-testing, anr

Can I view the ANR reports for my Internal Test releases? (Or any test releases for that matter?) For Production releases, there's and ANR widget on the main dashboard. For Internal Testing, there's nothing. Are the ANRs hidden somewhere? Thanks!

Comment: Does [this information](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/vitals/anr#trace-files) help?

Comment: @PaulT. Somewhat... Although, my testers are not technical people. So , asking them to install an SDK and a command line tool would cause their eyes to roll back in their heads! Also, I'm developing using MAUI.NET and Visual Studio and do not use Android Studio. I was hoping that I could get at the Testing ANRs via Google Play like I can with Production.  If not, I can go down the route of manually extracting them from the physical devices, but this is considerably less than ideal.

Comment: Ok, nothing was mentioned about "other testers", but I understand the complications.